Build a model for 3D object detection
I want to build a model for 3D object detection. I have taken scans of bottles (my object will be a bottle) by Intel RealSense depth camera. The file type is PCD or PLY (point cloud file). I have done labelling or annotation for each point cloud file by creating a 3D bounding box around the bottles to label them.
Most of the models available on the internet have been trained on KITTI dataset which is a 3D LiDAR dataset. I don't have data from LiDAR sensor, I just have depth-based point clouds (from Intel RealSense). I want help in building a model for such dataset. I have point clouds (.ply or .pcd) and labels (from CVAT online tool, available in Datumaro, KITTI and SLY point cloud formats) for each point cloud. Please suggest how I can build a model for 3D object detection.

Since you don’t have LiDAR data, you’ll need to adapt existing models or create custom ones.
Consider using deep learning-based models like YOLO (You Only Look Once), PointRCNN, or VoxelNet.
YOLOv5, for instance, can be trained on RGB-D data. You can use pre-trained weights and fine-tune them on your dataset.
Also check out this project by intel:
https://github.com/intel/depthcamera-3d-model-web-demo

Ok, I'll try this. Can you suggest something on the labels ?
Which format I should use them into. For the KITTI dataset, they have used .txt files for labels and I'm getting .json or .xml files from CVAT online tool (available export options are: Datumaro, KITTI and SLY Point cloud)
